# AngularJS how access to an object called "soap:Env" inside a JSON response

Tags: angularjs

I need to access a JSON object called `soap:Env` inside a JSON response. With the normal dot notation I can't. Is there another another way to avoid this problem?

```
 {  
   "soap:Envelope":{  
      "xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
      "xmlns:soap":"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
      "xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
      "soap:Body":{  
         "GetOwnersUsersResponse":{  
            "GetOwnersUsersResult":{  
               "ViewUser":[
```

There's an example of what i got as response.

Comment: Can you please show a small example with the structure of the json that you get as a response ?

Comment: You probably have to access it in another way using the syntax: `$json['soap:Env']` but an example of the JSON would help to confirm/deny that.

Comment: Added the example